# mysql wont start on my xamp how to fix this?

Tags: mysql, xampp

[image]

```
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using different port instead of 3306 you have to specify  it in config.inc.php.
For example if I am using 3308 port so i have to do
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3308
Below username and password extension.

Comment: The MySQL server isn't even started. The port is not the issue

Comment: Check Mysql log file you know the reason
for ex:
2021-02-22 12:53:07 5280 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-02-22 12:53:07 5280 [ERROR] Aborting